Question Nr.2: Are these cubbies or not in AmE?
I still don't know whether I can call the storage spaces I have put red circles around cubbyholes/cubbies because below my previous question many have given different answers and I just don't know who to believe and this is frustrating.
In this YouTube video, the woman build a similar piece of furniture with her husband and at 0:20 she refers to the very similar storage spaces as cubbies but native speakers seem to be all over the place when it comes to naming things and that's confusing.
Please note that I am not doing this to annoy you. I want to speak English naturally like a native speaker and I am a perfectionist and I find it super frustrating when answers are very different. It makes me despair, thinking that I might never achieve my goal.


Nobody is deliberately trying to confuse you, it's just that certain things don't have universally agreed upon names. This is especially true between countries, but may even be true within a certain area. I would call these "cubbies", but I am positive that even within my city, I could find people that disagree and might say something like "a cubby must be enclosed on all sides" or "a cubby must be square". They may use a different word, or they may not even have any word for this furniture configuration.

Language reflects the people who speak it. If you prefer a language with clear, complex/simple rules  and words whose meanings are inflexible  have not changed in centuries then you should study mathematics or music. You could attempt to study for the Proficiency English exam, level C2, which is really exacting, but will help broaden your vocabulary and think critically. Your questions don't always have a Boolean answer, sometimes the only true answer is "it depends"

Where's the link to the YouTube video, please?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEmVTaclcLU

You are double posting and that is not allowed: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/353392/are-the-storage-spaces-of-this-piece-of-furniture-called-cubby-holes-can-they-b

They're just "open-plan, open-fronted" cupboards / cabinets that not many people would really want in their own homes because they're untidy and don't provide for privacy. But obviously that's exactly what you want for common-access kindergarten schoolchildren's cupboards before they reach the age where they expect lockers. I can easily believe at least some of the adults in such environments call them cubbies because it's "baby-talk" for cupboards. They're certainly not "typical" cubby-holes, and there's obviously no other special dedicated term with any currency.

A cubby or cubby-hole is defined as "a small, snug place". There is no definition of what "small" means here. I don't know what language you speak, but if you go to a dictionary and look up "petite" or 小的 or صَغير or whatever is "small" in your language, does it give a measurement in centimetres? Or probably it would have to give multiple measurements because a small house is much bigger than a small mouth. If you want a more neutral word that doesn't depend on definitions of "small" and "snug", you could call the circled things "spaces" or "compartments".

As noted in the comments, these do not have one specific name, which is likely what is confusing to you. English is largely an imprecise language, and lots of things have names that vary between countries, regions within countries or even within just one region. If you assume that there is one name for every object or idea, you'll be very frustrated. Instead, know that many native speakers forget words all the time or encounter people who use different words from them, and that's okay. We're all accustomed to it!
Words for this type of object
Here are some ways that a native speaker might refer to this. The words you mentioned would definitely be the most common options:

cubby
cubby-hole

But, some native speakers might forget those words or not commonly use them and instead substitute any of the following while still being mostly understood in context:

shelf
storage shelf
storage area
coat rack


Thank you:-) Very reassuring. I already have an advanced level and I know that English isn't known for precision. But I find myself often frustrated and doubt my fluency because of the disconcertingly large degree of imprecision that English has.

@S635 I'm sorry but to say English is not known for precision, or any language for that matter is completely false. That said, a term like cubby or cubby-hole in American English not only refers to a small or narrow storage shelf (not area) but it also is a type of office. Fancy that. And everyone (as they say) know this in the States if they are native speakers.  Your picture just shows doorless closets, referred to in primary schools or kindergarden as cubbies. Older kids have lockers.

A cubby or cubby-hole is defined as "a small, snug place". There is no definition of what "small" means here. I don't know what language you speak, but if you go to a dictionary and look up "petite" or 小的 or صَغير or whatever is "small" in your language, does it give a measurement in centimetres? Or probably it would have to give multiple measurements because a small house is much bigger than a small mouth.

What are those things called then? You guys are making everything more complicated intentionally.

@S635 Yes, and I said that "known for precision" re English or any language is false. Knowing your goal, it's important to realize that. Any natural language can be used in a precise manner or not. It's not about the intrinsic nature of a language, it is how you use it. That's why highly complex technical documents can be sucessfully translated and people reading in either will understand them. "The rocket will still get to the moon".

I still don't who to believe though
